# Ribbon buttons aren't enabled when I use query string parameter with filter

Tags: ribbon, query-string

I have a problem adding filters with parameters in the lists.

I added a query string parameter. It is used in a filter. When I select one item in the list, most ribbon buttons (edit and delete, specially) aren't enabled. If I remove the filter, the ribbon buttons are enabled again. I need those ribbon buttons to stay enabled.

I thought that it was necessary to update the ribbon buttons with `RefreshCommandUI()`, but it didn't work.

How can I enable those buttons again?

Comment: SharePoint version?

Comment: My version is SharePoint Foundation 2010, but it is the same in SharePoint Server 2010

Comment: @Marlon: Can you explain more? where are you adding filters? which parameter or type of parameter?

Answer (score 1):

I actually found an answer to that problem.

Remove all querystring parameters. Then remove the corresponding filters.

Now, add another webpart: a querystring filter. Set it up to use the parameter you need.

Finally, connect both web parts (the querystring filter and the one displaying the list). Make it so that the querystring filter sends filter data do the list's filters.

Works like magic.

Comment: Filter web parts are not available in Sharepoint Foundation, which is what he was referring to in his comments.